# scp -q isn't quiet between different hosts

Tags: linux, scp

So `scp -q file host:file`  and `scp -q host:file file` are both quiet, i.e. don't give the progress meter.  But when I run `scp -q host1:file host2:file`, I still get the progress meter as well as a `Connection to host1 closed.` message.  The progress meter can be gotten rid of by redirected `stdout` to `/dev/null` (although I'd rather not have to), but the connection closed messages comes on `stderr`, which I definitely want to keep in case there's a real error.  How can I make scp quiet? Do I have to run `ssh host1 "scp -q file host2:file"`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in host1, edit ~/.ssh/config and add something like this

```
Host host2
    LogLevel=QUIET
```

this will turn the messages off for you.

because -q only controls the ssh client connection from your localhost, not from host1.

Comment: You can also specify this at the command line, e.g.: `scp -q -o LogLevel=QUIET /tmp/foo someotherhost:/tmp`

Comment: @Banjer Thanks for the `-q -o LogLevel`. Works perfectly!